# why core data can't save NSNumber value?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, boolean, nsnumber

I create NSNumber, use bool value control NSNumber.

I build simulator, core data have NSNumber data.

but i turn off simulator. Restart simulator again. NSNumber data not see

thank you for help.

core data value

```
@NSManaged public var cIsLike: NSNumber

 var isLike: Bool {
        get {
            return Bool(truncating: cIsLike)
        }
        set {
            cIsLike = NSNumber(value: newValue)
        }
    }
```

change bool and save data code

```
private let moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    private var videoArray = [CoreVideo]()
    
    init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = moc

    }


func updateVideo(currentVideo video: CoreVideo, isLike newValue: Bool) {
        video.isLike = newValue
        save()
    }
    

 private func save() {
        do {
            try moc.save()
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Save failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not declare it as Bool directly, `@NSManaged public var cIsLike: Bool`?

Comment: i use Bool, core data no effect, i see other say need to use NSNumber. core data can save.

Comment: Then the problem is most likely in some other part of your code not included here.

Comment: i use api, maybe problem is this. thank you.